# Copy and paste rows from Excel to Powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Ok, here is what I am looking for (Im new, so be gentle):

- Copy and paste (default format) from excel to powerpoint (from just the one sheet)
- I can only fit so many rows in ppt - so after a slide fills, I want ppt to create a new slide
- Same title for each slide is fine!
- I only need columns B:K copied over

That's it, however I am stuck :(  I know the below code is NOT the best way to write this and it contains errors in which I am sure will be easy to spot. I cannot find how to do this anywhere on the net.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim mySlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim myShapeRange As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim i As Integer

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)

 For i = 1 To 6
  'need to set focus to slde 1
   PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (1)

  'Deletes Title
  'mySlide.Shapes.Title.Delete

  'builds new title
  mySlide.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, left:=9, Top:=6, Width:=702, Height:=30
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).Line.Visible = msoTrue
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Size = 20
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignLeft
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Current Full Initiative Details – Branded Book as of " & Date
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).Name = "I am TITLE"
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).Line.Weight = 1
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).Fill.Visible = msoTrue
  mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

  'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW").Range("B1:K23")

  'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy

  'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial DataType:=ppPasteDefault

  Set myShapeRange = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

  'Set position:
  myShapeRange.left = 10
  myShapeRange.Top = 42
  myShapeRange.Height = 492
  myShapeRange.Width = 702

  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RAW").Rows("2:23").Delete

  Call myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly)

  'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! **1)** Remove `On Error Resume Next` - that will take any error message and throw it away as if it never happened. There's no telling what's going on with that in there. **2)** Is there something that you're expecting it to do that it's not? i.e. Is this functional code that you'd like to make better, or is there something broken?  If there's something not working, you'll get a better response if you say _what_ isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for the edits (looks nice).  The code isn't working as intended.  1)It does not populate the title on every slide. 2)It does not automatically stop when it reaches the last row in my worksheet.3.)It does not resize what is pasted in the ppt.  This is a edit from an existing code font floating around the internet.  All I can think of is a fixed loop, but that wouldnt do what I would want it to do.

Comment: Since ppt 2003 the slides object has a method "addslide", not "add". I don't know what this chganges [ppt Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff746586.aspx). When you use activesheet, activeworkbook, activewindow etc. make sure that you refer to the object you really want. A better way is to use the index or name (by the way you try to give all slides the same name). I would recommend instead of "PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (1)" to use "Powerpointapp.slides(1)"

Comment: This code is just a rather lame attempt in showing what I am trying to do.  I just want to copy all the rows on one worksheet over to a powerpoint.  I want to continue to build on the slides until the data runs out.  Have been working on this all day and cannot figure it out :(

Comment: @Yogwhatup; please use the @christineross, so I wil be informed about your response;
What I don't understand: The Excel Range "B1:K23" should be placed on one  slide or divided over 6 slides? If Yes, it should be divided in chunks and you shouldn't copy it at once. If it should be done automatic you need a rule how split in chunks; line by line, named blocks or whatever. Unfortunately there is no macro recorder available in powerpoint. So I would recommend that you write down in plain language what you want to do step by step and then try to use vba

Comment: @christineross All I am really trying to do is copy all of the rows in a worksheet over to a powerpoint.  I want to let the code run so it copies and pastes the rows into as many PPT slides as necessary, then stop.

Comment: @FreeMan have you seen this anywhere?  I cannot be the only one that has requested this, however I can't find the answer anywhere on the net.

Comment: I'm am doing something similar, but I have a PPT slide that is manually set up to `LINK` to the XLS. I copy the slide, then update the link to point to where I want it. Not sure, though, exactly how this will work for you, since I'm putting on predefined charts, not unknown numbers of rows of data. You may want to look into that, though. Unfortunately, MS, in their infinite wisdom, decided there was no need for a macro recorder in PPT, so it makes it vital to learn the docs/object model.

Comment: By `LINK` I mean: 1) copy in XLS, 2) in PPT, click Paste drop down, 3) Special, 4) Link (in PPT2010). This way you have a live link to your XLS sheet. Once there, the link source can be modified on what it points to. You'd have to play with that to figure out how to make it point at a new set of rows.

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what you're after, but it may demonstrate a few techniques that'll help (disclaimer: PPTFAQ is my site, though the code in the example is from a few colleagues of mine, published there with their permission)  http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00892_Using_Excel_and_Access_data_in_PowerPoint_Tables_-by_Brian_Reilly_and_Naresh_Nichani-.htm

Comment: @FreeMan Can you fwd any bit of code that may help?  Deadline is closing in on me and I have nothing for this portion of my code :(  I have gone to the end of the internet!  Nothing.

Comment: This was another suggestion, but I dont know how to incorporate!
I suggest you post this question on an Excel forum as I unfortunately don't have the bandwidth to solve situational problems currently. Let's say you can fit 100 rows on a slide, I would suspect your logic would need to look something like this:

For x=1 to 3000/100

'Create new slide

'Loop through each row and paste over

For y = 1 to 100

Row(z).copy then paste

Next y

Next x

Hopefully, that helps give you a general direction. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested in comments, here is the code I use to copy a slide from a master PPT template to the report PPT.

There is some extraneous code in there to provide status updates on the form we use to drive the process, as well as a debugging flag that I can toggle on/off at run time - these can both be removed.

**This will serve as a starting point to finding the proper solution for your situation, and is not a complete answer to the question as asked.**

```
'I've chosen to declare these globally, though it's probably not the best way:
Dim PPTObj As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPTMaster As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPTClinic As PowerPoint.Presentation


Private Sub InsertPPT(ByVal SlideName As String, ByVal StatusText As String)

Dim Shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim Top As Single
Dim Left As Single
Dim Height As Single
Dim width As Single


  PPTMaster.Slides(SlideName).Copy
  PPTClinic.Slides.Paste
  Form_Master.ProcessStatus.Value = StatusText & " InsertPPT"
  With PPTClinic.Slides(PPTClinic.Slides.count)
    If Debugging Then
      .Select
    End If
    .Design = PPTMaster.Slides(SlideName).Design              'this ensures we get all the right formatting - only seems to be necessary 1 time, but we'll just do it on all
    .ColorScheme = PPTMaster.Slides(SlideName).ColorScheme
    .FollowMasterBackground = PPTMaster.Slides(SlideName).FollowMasterBackground
    For Each Shp In .Shapes                                                 'loop through all the shapes on the slide
      If Debugging Then
'          .Select
        Shp.Select
      End If
      Form_Master.ProcessStatus.Value = StatusText & " InsertPPT-" & Shp.Name
      If Shp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then                                 'when we find a linked one
        ReLinkShape Shp, TempVars!NewXLName
        'need to store off top, left, width, height
        Top = Shp.Top
        Left = Shp.Left
        Height = Shp.Height
        width = Shp.width
        Shp.LinkFormat.Update                                               'and force the link to refresh
        MySleep 2, "S"                                                      'hopefully, the 2 second pause will allow everything to update properly before moving on.
        'then reset them here - they seem to change shape when I update them
        Shp.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        Shp.Top = Top
        Shp.Left = Left
        Shp.width = width
        Shp.Height = Height
      ElseIf Shp.Name = "SlideName" And Not Debugging Then                  'if it's the "SlideName" tag
        Shp.Delete                                                          'delete it (unless we're debugging)
      End If
    Next
  End With

  Form_Master.ProcessStatus.Value = StatusText

End Sub

Private Sub ReLinkShape(ByRef Shp As PowerPoint.Shape, ByVal NewDestination As String)

  Dim Link() As String
  Dim link2() As String

  If Shp.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then                                 'when we find a linked one
    Link = Split(Shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName, "!")                    'update the link to point to the new clinic spreadsheet instead of the master
    If InStr(1, Link(2), "]") > 0 Then
      link2 = Split(Link(2), "]")
      Link(2) = "[" & TempVars!ClinicName & ".xlsx]" & link2(1)
    End If

    Shp.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = NewDestination & "!" & Link(1) & "!" & Link(2)
  End If

End Sub

Public Sub MySleep(ByRef Unit As Double, ByRef UOM As String)

Dim Pause As Date

  Pause = DateAdd(UOM, Unit, Now())
  While Now < Pause
    DoEvents
  Wend

End Sub
```